# What content-type must be used when sending a request with form-data in Postman

Tags: rest, http, request, http-post, postman

When sending a json data like:

```
{
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "password": "secret"
}
```

it is used on **Headers** > `Content-type: application/json` and in **Body** > **raw** it is copied the above json text.

[image]

But how to do it if we need also an **image** beside the email and password?

I changed the **Body** to **form-data** like here

[image]

and set the Content-type to `image/png` but it is not working.

Is there a way to send in the same POST request some strings (email, password) and also an image?

Comment: What programming language do you use at server side?

Comment: @Div I'm using node.js

Comment: What version of Postman is that, looks very old :(

Comment: it is: Postman for Chrome
Version 5.5.4
linux / x86-64
Chrome 80.0.3987.149

Comment: Yikes. 2 Major versions behind. You're missing out on a lot of things.

Comment: but still, is that such a big problem?

Comment: Have you tired with `multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: The newer version would have set the header for you :)

Comment: @LeoMessi Usually, to accept both, file and json, in a single request, required code changes. I'm not sure about node but I'm saying from my exp. with c#